# 64bit VBA call to open windows form in external .dll

Tags: .net, vba, vb.net, com-interop

Hoping to get some help with an issue that has been frustrating me for a couple of days despite searching for an answer to my issue on here and elsewhere

I have written a VB.Net addin that plugs into the API of Alphacam. I have this addin working corectly at numerous sites already. The current sites are all using 32bit VBA and my addin has been compiled to x86 which works fine, but Alphacam now only uses 64bit VBA. 
The Visual Studio project is set to make the .dll COM-Visible and Register For COM Interop. 
I have the VBA project working out which VBA is being used as follows which then calls the appropriate .dll

```
#If VBA7 Then
'Set up menu to suit 64bit VBA
'Collect button clicks to call Function to call numerous forms in 64bit .dll

'Call About Form in .dll
Public Function CallAboutForm()
Dim MyAboutForm As New My64BitDLL.AboutForm
MyAboutForm.show
End Function

Else

Endif
```

The addin is installed using AdvancedInstaller to a machine specific path so that Alphacam can find the VBA project to load the menu. The .dll and .tlb files are installed to the same location.

On my development machine the code works as expected but when addin is installed on a production machine it fails at 'MyAboutForm.show' and the error message says 'Run-time error '429' ActiveX component can't create object'.

I have tried calling the form as follows as well

```
Dim MyAboutForm As Object
Set MyAboutForm = New My64Bitdll.AboutForm
MyAboutForm.Show
```

This also works as expected on the development machine but not a production machine.

Have also tried using AdvancedInstaller to register the .dll alone, the .tlb alone as well as registering both .dll and .tlb files together. Have also tried with no AdvancedInstaller registration. Regardless of the registration used the error is the same.

The VBA compiles as expected on the production machine but when the VBA calls the .dll it fails

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Very likely missing dependencies. First ensure you have .net runtime of suitable version. Then use sysinternals process monitor, it will likely tell you which dll wasn’t found.

Comment: For a given progid, it's easy to check if your DLL is registered, check registry HKCR\<progid>\etc.. for 64-bit components. or HKCR\WOW6432Node\<progid>\etc... for 32-bit components

Comment: *"#If VBA7 Then 'Set up menu to suit 64bit VBA"* - FYI the VBA7 directive does not detect 64 bit installs, just the runtime version, WIN64 detects bitness.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will look into these suggestions tonight and report back with my findings. Again many thanks.